# How can I identify a salvaged LCD? 21 pins

Tags: arduino, identification, soldering, lcd

I did something that might be considered bad practice. I desoldered an LCD from a fan heater by silvercrest and i'm having some trouble identifying the pinout of it. From what I can tell, pin 1 is GND and pin 2 is VCC but i'm quite new at this and couldn't find any datasheet at all. It's 21 pins, and then a seperate LED backlight.

The different sections of the LCD light up when the LCD is connected to power and you ground the different pins. My goal would be to use the numbers in the right lower corner with an arduino. Any help is appreciated! Here's the PCB I desoldered it from

[image: img]

And here's a video of me grounding the different pins while pin1 and 2 are connected to GND/5v
https://streamable.com/0gx7hi

Comment: You can buy an LCD for $9 (or less), reverse engineering this salvaged part is not trivial. https://www.amazon.com/SunFounder-Serial-Module-Display-Arduino/dp/B019K5X53O

Comment: You'd have had far more luck figuring it out when it was still operating in the original product.  If you understand how LCD's work, you can get an MCU to toggle two pins out of phase, put some resistors on for safety and go probing pin pairs and see if you can identify segments/columns.  But using undocumented devices isn't on topic here.

Comment: what's the point of posting a picture of the front of the board? ... first, the question is not about the board ... second, the back of the board is where the connections are visible ... between the LCD and the board, you could have posted 4 pictures

Comment: These are segment lcds. Typically need an AC signal to drive the pins but can be done by pulsing an output high to low. Google "arduino segment lcd" for some examples. Alternatively you can get segment lcd driver ICs. Or as suggested just pick up a character or digit lcd with controller board.

Comment: Very high chance this is a 'custom' LCD, and ergo no data will ever surface for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The different sections of the LCD light up when the LCD is connected
> to power and you ground the different pins.

The number of pins and segments on your display suggest that it is a multiplexed display similar to this:-

[image]

You can determine the pinout of your LCD by noting which segment activates when you apply a voltage between any two pins. After recording the response to all possible pin combinations you should be able to produce a segment layout map similar to the one above.

Each LCD segment is 'lit' (changes polarization) when a high enough voltage is applied between its segment 'row' (number) and common 'column' (letter). To avoid lighting other unwanted segments at the same time, multiple voltage levels are applied. Only those segments with a voltage difference exceeding the LCD's threshold voltage will 'light'. To avoid damaging the display the average voltage across each segment must equate to zero (ie. AC voltage only applied), so all the voltages must be periodically inverted.

Shown below are examples of 3 and 4 level drive voltage waveforms. Only the periods shown in orange have enough voltage difference to 'light' the segment.

[image]

To produce the multilevel voltages, resistor dividers can be applied to the MCU I/O pins, like this:-

[image]

The 3 levels are produced by setting the I/O pin high, low, or open circuit (when the resistors set the voltage to 1/2 Vcc). Your driver board has several resistors on it that might perform this function.

All the images above come from an article which describes how to drive this type of display from an AVR MCU.

[Awawa's Lab: Direct LCD drive by AVR GPIO](http://awawa.hariko.com/avr_lcd_drive_en.html)